# Hide a div when page is still, show on scroll movement up

Tags: jquery, header, scroll, sticky, jquery-scrollable

I want to do a sticky header like that on chrome (?) on android.

ie, as you scroll down the page, there is no sticky header, but as soon as you scroll up, (or after say 1 second) the sticky header appears again.

Then, when you scroll down it hides once more.

I think this is a far better sticky header solution but can only find tutorials that refer to waypoints, and I want something based on movement, not fixed positions.

Can someone give me a bare bones example of this?

Would be great, thanks.

Comment: Why dont you use a responsive framework like Foundation?

Comment: we already use bootstrap, but this kind falls outside of the envelope.  I found http://jsfiddle.net/frZ9j/9/ which is very similar to what we need, except that the following tweaks are needed:

1. starts off as hidden
2. waits for say a scroll up of 100px to fade in

Comment: foundation looks great though.  I just hate learning diff versions of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frZ9j/55/) .I hope this is what you need..

```
var scroll_pos = 50;
var scroll_time;
if($('.gridContainer').is(':visible'))
 $('.gridContainer').addClass('hidden');  
$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(scroll_time);
    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (current_scroll >= $('#topNav').outerHeight()) {
    if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos + 100) {
        $('.gridContainer').removeClass('hidden');    
    }
    else {
        $('.gridContainer').addClass('hidden');  
    }
}

scroll_time = setTimeout(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
}, 600);
```

});

Comment: thanks but not quite.  1. nav is hidden by default and doesn't gt activated until user scrolls up. 2. nav then shows for 5 seconds and fades out UNLESS the user scrolls up again in which case the timer is RESET and the 5 second countdown starts again. 3. when the window shows the top 100px of the page, the nav hides again by default.  in your version it seems the auto fadeout isn't working at all....